# C# Telegram Bot Api ReplyKeyboardMarkup using html inside

Tags: c#, api, telegram

I wantto write telegram bot using https://github.com/TelegramBots/telegram.bot
I want to use html tags inside KeyboardButton. I'm trying like this:

```
public static ReplyKeyboardMarkup rkmStartButton
    {
        get
        {
            KeyboardButton btnCanal = new KeyboardButton("<b>bold</b>");

            ReplyKeyboardMarkup rkmStartButton = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup();
            rkmStartButton.ResizeKeyboard = true;

            rkmStartButton.Keyboard = new KeyboardButton[][]
            {
               new KeyboardButton[]
               {
                   btnCanal
               }
              };

            return rkmStartButton;
        }
    }
```

But in telegram button text looks like < b > bold < / b >, must be: **bold**
I try many variants, but they still doesnot work. How i can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't format keyboard button texts at this time, you can make a suggestion to [@BotSupport](https://t.me/BotSupport).